# Ambient Data Framework Requirements?

Tags: 2011, ambient-data-framework

I understand the Ambient Data Framework (ADF) is a content delivery module that consists of claims, claims processors, and cartridges meant to help gather, configure, and transform Web- and user-related data.

What do customers need to implement ADF (e.g. setting up [Bart Koopman's Quova Ambient Data Framework eXtension](http://sdltridionworld.com/community/2011_extensions/Quova_ADF.aspx))?

So far, I'm thinking we just need:

- A Content Delivery setup (and license)
- Java for input and output claims (limited .NET API also available)

Also, SmartTarget requires ADF. But to use ADF, do we need SmartTarget?

Comment: You don't need Smart Target to use ADF. ADF is required for the Session Preview feature of XPM. Using the cd_webservice_preview_cartridge &  footprint_cartridge_conf cartridges against the CD Webservice

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ambient Data Framework requires the following:

- A valid Tridion license
- A Java Runtime Environment
- A correctly configured Tridion Content Delivery stack
- cd_ambient.jar & its configuration, cd_ambient_conf.xml
- A configured web.xml (J2EE) or web.config (.NET) with the configuration to start the J2EE Ambient Data Framework `Filter` or the .NET Ambient Data Framework `Module`

Please note that the pre-configured webapp samples that ship with Tridion Content Delivery have all the pre-requisites already, so if you use those you don't need any additional files.

Various Tridion modules use the Ambient Framework:

- Audience Manager
- Experience Manager (Session Preview)
- SmartTarget
- Online Marketing Explorer (tracking)

You can use the Ambient Framework for your own purposes, without any of the above modules.

Comment: Thanks for explaining relationship between modules, Nuno. I can also see the 2013 documentation specifically mentions the examples available in the CD roles. Cool!